# Bootstrap sync SVG size with text size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently found this svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M524.531,69.836a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-.764-.7A485.065,485.065,0,0,0,404.081,32.03a1.816,1.816,0,0,0-1.923.91,337.461,337.461,0,0,0-14.9,30.6,447.848,447.848,0,0,0-134.426,0,309.541,309.541,0,0,0-15.135-30.6,1.89,1.89,0,0,0-1.924-.91A483.689,483.689,0,0,0,116.085,69.137a1.712,1.712,0,0,0-.788.676C39.068,183.651,18.186,294.69,28.43,404.354a2.016,2.016,0,0,0,.765,1.375A487.666,487.666,0,0,0,176.02,479.918a1.9,1.9,0,0,0,2.063-.676A348.2,348.2,0,0,0,208.12,430.4a1.86,1.86,0,0,0-1.019-2.588,321.173,321.173,0,0,1-45.868-21.853,1.885,1.885,0,0,1-.185-3.126c3.082-2.309,6.166-4.711,9.109-7.137a1.819,1.819,0,0,1,1.9-.256c96.229,43.917,200.41,43.917,295.5,0a1.812,1.812,0,0,1,1.924.233c2.944,2.426,6.027,4.851,9.132,7.16a1.884,1.884,0,0,1-.162,3.126,301.407,301.407,0,0,1-45.89,21.83,1.875,1.875,0,0,0-1,2.611,391.055,391.055,0,0,0,30.014,48.815,1.864,1.864,0,0,0,2.063.7A486.048,486.048,0,0,0,610.7,405.729a1.882,1.882,0,0,0,.765-1.352C623.729,277.594,590.933,167.465,524.531,69.836ZM222.491,337.58c-28.972,0-52.844-26.587-52.844-59.239S193.056,219.1,222.491,219.1c29.665,0,53.306,26.82,52.843,59.239C275.334,310.993,251.924,337.58,222.491,337.58Zm195.38,0c-28.971,0-52.843-26.587-52.843-59.239S388.437,219.1,417.871,219.1c29.667,0,53.307,26.82,52.844,59.239C470.715,310.993,447.538,337.58,417.871,337.58Z"/></svg>
```

And im trying to display that SVG alongside some text

I tried to do the following

```
<h1>(Svg element here)Contact us</h1>
```

However the size is wayyy too large is there any way I can ensure that the SVG is the same size as the text ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plain css.
Since your svg has a `viewBox` defining it's aspect ratio, you can apply a height relative to the parent HTML element's font-size.
Your icon will scale similarly to an icon font character.

```
.svg-icon {
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: 0.9em;
  /* optional vertical/baseline shift */
  transform: translateY(0.125em);
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.svg-icon {
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: 0.9em;
  /* optional vertical/baseline shift */
  transform: translateY(0.125em);
}

.h1-custom {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1-custom"><svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <use href="#fa-discord" />
  </svg> Contact us</h1>

<h1><svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <use href="#fa-discord" />
  </svg> Contact us</h1>

<h2><svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <use href="#fa-discord" />
  </svg> Contact us</h2>

<h3><svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <use href="#fa-discord" />
  </svg> Contact us</h3>

<p><svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <use href="#fa-discord" />
  </svg> Contact us</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="fa-discord" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M524.531,69.836a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-.764-.7A485.065,485.065,0,0,0,404.081,32.03a1.816,1.816,0,0,0-1.923.91,337.461,337.461,0,0,0-14.9,30.6,447.848,447.848,0,0,0-134.426,0,309.541,309.541,0,0,0-15.135-30.6,1.89,1.89,0,0,0-1.924-.91A483.689,483.689,0,0,0,116.085,69.137a1.712,1.712,0,0,0-.788.676C39.068,183.651,18.186,294.69,28.43,404.354a2.016,2.016,0,0,0,.765,1.375A487.666,487.666,0,0,0,176.02,479.918a1.9,1.9,0,0,0,2.063-.676A348.2,348.2,0,0,0,208.12,430.4a1.86,1.86,0,0,0-1.019-2.588,321.173,321.173,0,0,1-45.868-21.853,1.885,1.885,0,0,1-.185-3.126c3.082-2.309,6.166-4.711,9.109-7.137a1.819,1.819,0,0,1,1.9-.256c96.229,43.917,200.41,43.917,295.5,0a1.812,1.812,0,0,1,1.924.233c2.944,2.426,6.027,4.851,9.132,7.16a1.884,1.884,0,0,1-.162,3.126,301.407,301.407,0,0,1-45.89,21.83,1.875,1.875,0,0,0-1,2.611,391.055,391.055,0,0,0,30.014,48.815,1.864,1.864,0,0,0,2.063.7A486.048,486.048,0,0,0,610.7,405.729a1.882,1.882,0,0,0,.765-1.352C623.729,277.594,590.933,167.465,524.531,69.836ZM222.491,337.58c-28.972,0-52.844-26.587-52.844-59.239S193.056,219.1,222.491,219.1c29.665,0,53.306,26.82,52.843,59.239C275.334,310.993,251.924,337.58,222.491,337.58Zm195.38,0c-28.971,0-52.843-26.587-52.843-59.239S388.437,219.1,417.871,219.1c29.667,0,53.307,26.82,52.844,59.239C470.715,310.993,447.538,337.58,417.871,337.58Z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Adjust the `font-size` to the desired result.
Besides, you can wrap your svg path in a [`<symbol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) element and reuse it by placing [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) elements.